# How to remove a body properly in box2d?

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I have a lot of bodies with same `BodyDef` in Box2D and when I call:

```
Array<Body> bodies = new Array<Body>();
world.getBodies(bodies);
for(Body b : bodies){
    if(b.getPosition().y < -20f) {
        world.destroyBody(b);
    }
}
```

it destroys all of the bodies with that `BodyDef`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not referencing any `BodyDef` here.

```
world.destroyBody(b);
```

should only destroy body `b`. Just make sure that your `if` condition is ok. You could also debug step by step (or put a log inside the `if`), just to check if the number of bodies destroyed is the same as the times the `if` condition is `true`.

Comment: Yes it looks like the problem is in the if loop.
I put this in if loop:

    System.out.println(b.getPosition().y);

and it always prints out 0.0 although all the bodies have different position. Do you maybe know why is that so?

Comment: I was writing just now :) Problem solved then? Strangely, if body positions are all 0.0, the if condition is supposedly to be always `false`, isn't it?

Comment: i changed it slightly after asking the question :)